# C function to check if array is balanced (recursive)

Tags: c

Im trying to write a function which checks whether an array is balanced or not. I came up with the following:

```
//Defining my struct

struct tuples
{
    bool trueorfalse;
    int sum;
};

typedef struct tuples tuple; //Renaming it to "tuple"

//Defining my function

tuple balanced(int A[], int l, int r)
{
    if(l == r) // Base case 
    {
        tuple s;
        s.trueorfalse = true;
        s.sum = A[l];

        return s;
    }

    tuple left; //Creating tuple for the left side of the array
    tuple right; //Creating tuple for the right side of the array

    int m = (l+r)/2; //Computing the middle

    left = balanced(A, l, m); //recursive call for the left side
    right = balanced(A,m+1, r); //recursive call for the right side 

    if(left.trueorfalse && right.trueorfalse && left.sum >= (right.sum / 2.0f) && left.sum <= right.sum *2) //Check the conditions to be a balanced array on the subarrays
    {
        tuple f; //If this is the case create a new tuple with true and the sum

        f.trueorfalse = true;
        f.sum = left.sum + right.sum;

        return f;
    }
    else
    {
        tuple g; 
        g.trueorfalse = false;
        g.sum = left.sum + right.sum;

        return g;
    }


}
```

But this seems to work fine for a few examples but not for all. Example: A =[1,2,5,2,4,2] is a balanced tree but my function doesn't return a struct with value true.

EDIT:

We defined balanced as following:

- the sum of the elements in the first half is no more than
  double and no less than half the sum of the elements in the
  second half, and
- the first and second half are balanced

Comment: Your question should include the *precise* definition of "balanced". We shouldn't have to derive that definition from code that you've already admitted doesn't necessarily work correctly.

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right. I've made an edit and added the definition of balanced.

Comment: What's the expected behavior with odd count arrays ? Can't you use for loop instead of recursion ?

Comment: @GabrielT Unfortunately, it isn't specified. But I assume that if I have for example A = [1,2,3] the first subarray will be [1,2] and the second [3]. 

I need to have recursive solution.  But I'm still curious: regarding time complexity, should one in general prefer iterative solutions?

Comment: Your definition of what a balanced array is is recursive and thus invalid. `We defined balanced as following: ... bla bla... the first and second half are balanced`. So basically your write it's balanced when it's balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. 
Btw with what you stated about odd arrays A =[1,2,5,2,4,2] is not balanced because A[3]+A[4] > A[5]*2

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct 
{
    bool trueorfalse;
    int sum;
}tuple;

tuple balanced(int A[], int size);
bool Is_Balanced(int a, int b);

int main(void) 
{ 
 int A[]={1,2,5,2,4,2};
 tuple res =balanced(A,6);
 if(res.trueorfalse)printf("balanced");
 else printf("notbalanced");
}

tuple balanced(int A[], int size)
{
    if(size<4)//maximum recursion depth
    {
        tuple s;
        if(size==3) s.trueorfalse = Is_Balanced((*(A)+*(A+1)),*(A+2));
        else s.trueorfalse = Is_Balanced(*(A),*(A+1));
        s.sum = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)s.sum += *(A+i);
        return s;
    }

    tuple left;
    tuple right;

    left = balanced(A, size/2);
    right = balanced(A+size/2, size/2);

    tuple f;
    if(left.trueorfalse && right.trueorfalse)
      f.trueorfalse = Is_Balanced(left.sum,right.sum);
    else f.trueorfalse = false;
    f.sum = left.sum + right.sum;
    return f;
}

bool Is_Balanced(int a, int b)
{
  return (a<=(2*b) && a>=(2/b)?true:false);
}
```